# SSHFS fails, Error - read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: scp, fstab, sshfs

SCP is working, but the sshfs is displaying the above error.

```
sudo sshfs -o allow_other -o transform_symlinks username@192.168.2.207:/ /media/SSHFS_bbb
```

Comment: You are saying `sudo scp username@192.168.2.207:/etc/profile /tmp` works, while the `sshfs` command above doesn't?

Comment: Hi @tharunkumar, welcome to Unix & Linux. Please do not post a question and answer in the same place. If you have found the answer, answer to yourself in the answer box.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution - host key is changed, Need to update it.

update the Host key of the IP address

```
sudo ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.168.2.207
```

After this `sshfs` is working, I am able to mount the complete file system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have done:
`-o ssh_command='sshpass -p xxx ssh'`
 password is right, and get "Connection reset by peer", after remove the option, succeed.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was the `ControlPath` ssh-config value which couldn't handle the connectionURI (in my case a stack-url containing @).
I changed my `ControlPath` in `~/.ssh/config` to:

```
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%C
```

and then it worked

ps. make sure the sockets-dir exists (run `mkdir ~/.ssh/sockets` e.g.)